# Adding Google Calendars to a user via API & domain delegation doesn't set colours

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I'm pushing calendars to my G Suite domain users using the python API. I want to be able to specify the colour that a calendar appears in a user's feed, but the calendars always come out the same boring blue.

Here's where the calendar gets added (this works as the calendar appears in the user's list, but ignoring the colours)

```
def google_add_cals_to_user(self, user):
    cals = GoogleCalendar.objects.calendars_for_user(user)
    cal_client = self.setup_user_cal(user.email)
    for cal in cals:
        cal_body = {
            'selected': True,
            'id': cal.address,
            'colorRgbFormat': True,
            'foregroundColor': '#000000',
            'backgroundColor': '#' + cal.colour
        }
        self.execute(cal_client.calendarList().insert(body=cal_body))
```

Here's where the calendar service gets built:

```
def setup_user_cal(self, email):
    logger.debug('building calendar service for %s' % email)
    http_cal = self.key_auth(email, scopes=SCOPES_CAL)
    return self.build_service('calendar', 'v3', http_cal)
```

And the auth code:

```
def key_auth(self, user_email, scopes=SCOPES, http=None):
    """
     This sets up auth using a private key set up as per: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/delegation
    """
    f = file(settings.GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, 'rb')
    key = f.read()
    f.close()
    credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(settings.GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, key,
                                                scope=scopes, sub=user_email)
    if not http:
        http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credentials.authorize(http)
    return http
```

And build_service:

```
def build_service(self, serviceName, version, http):
    retries = 10
    for n in range(1, retries+1):
        try:
            return build(serviceName, version, http=http)
        except AccessTokenRefreshError, e:
            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

[Calendars.insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert) takes a calendar id and a calendar body as parameters

> In the request body, supply a [Calendars resource](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars#resource) with the following properties:

If you check the documentation for a calendars resource you will see

```
{
  "kind": "calendar#calendar",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": string,
  "summary": string,
  "description": string,
  "location": string,
  "timeZone": string
}
```

As you can see those are the only fields you are allowed to insert.  Color is not among them.  I checked [calendars.patch](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/patch) as well and you cant even update the calendars color.

Normally I would suggest you add an feature request for it.  However I cant see to find an issue forum for Google calendar API.

Comment: I tried using the API explorer on my own account, and successfully managed to insert a calendar with a specific colour, so it seems that it is possible. In any case, I'm using calendarList.insert

Comment: have you tried patching an existing calendar.list then?  https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/patch  after it is inserted?